# is using cudaHostAlloc good for my case

Tags: c++, c, cuda, gpu, gpgpu

i have a kernel launched several times, untill a solution is found. the solution will be found by at least one block.
therefore when a block finds the solution it should inform the cpu that the solution is found, so the cpu prints the solution provided by this block.
so what i am currently doing is the following:

```
__global__ kernel(int sol)
{
   //do some computations
   if(the block found a solution)
        sol = blockId.x //atomically
}
```

now on every call to the kernel i copy sol back to the host memory and check its value. if its set to 3 for example, i know that blockid 3 found the solution so i now know where the index of the solution start, and copy the solution back to the host.
in this case, will using cudaHostAlloc be a better option? more over would copying the value of a single integer on every kernel call slows down my program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issuing a copy from GPU to CPU and then waiting for its completion will slow your program *a bit*. Note that if you choose to send 1 byte or 1KB, that won't make much of a difference. In this case bandwidth is not a problem, but latency.

But launching a kernel does consume some time as well. If the "meat" of your algorithm is in the kernel itself I wouldn't spend too much time on that single, small transfer.

Do note, if you choose to use the mapped memory, instead of using `cudaMemcpy`, you will need to explicitly put a `cudaDeviceSynchronise` (or `cudaThreadSynchronise` with older CUDA) barrier (as opposed to an implicit barrier at `cudaMemcpy`) before reading the status. Otherwise, your host code may go achead reading an old value stored in your pinned memory, before the kernel overwrites it.

Comment: With CUDA 4.0 it is `cudaDeviceSynchronize()`, `cudaThreadSynchronize()` is deprecated.

Comment: @harrism Any idea on what is the difference between cudaDeviceSynchronize() and cudaThreadSynchronize() ? I guess they are intended to do the same thing, but why change the name ?

Comment: They do exactly the same thing.  The name was changed because originally intended that you would have one host thread per device context, so `cudaThreadSynchronize()` would be used to synchronize (aka wait for completion of) all CUDA calls from a single host thread.  Now a single host thread can control multiple device contexts, so the call `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` is used to synchronize all CUDA calls to a single device, and `cudaThreadSynchronize()` is deprecated.